# Error al ejecutar comando grumphp: se alcanzó el límite de entrada

Tags: php, windows, powershell

Al correr la tarea phpmd dentro de grumphp, mediante el comando:

```
./vendor/bin/grumphp run --tasks phpmd
```

me surge el siguiente error:

> Running task 1/1: phpmd...
>   Oh no, we hit the windows cmd input limit!
>   Skipping task...

He leido en múltiples publicaciones que hay que aumentar el `cmd input limit`, pero no he podido dar con una implementación que me funcione.
Estoy usando Windows PowerShell como consola y tengo windows 10, cualquier sugerencia bienvenida sea.